# no implicit reference conversion error in a generic repository and generic DbContext

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I use a generic repository in my program but when I describe context as a generic context it causes a error:

> **Error   1    The type**
>   'ArchiveBoundedContext.Infrastructure.Contexts.ArchiveBoundedContext'
>   **cannot be used as type parameter** 'TContext' **in the generic type or
>   method** 'SharedKernel.Infrastructure.Repository'. 
>   **There is no implicit reference conversion from**
>   'ArchiveBoundedContext.Infrastructure.Contexts.ArchiveBoundedContext'
>   **to** 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.
>   f:\Last Version Of Projects\Archiver-master\SharedKernel.Infrastructure\bin\Debug\SharedKernel.Infrastructure.dll
>   ArchiveBoundedContext.Application

**Generic Repository:**

```
    public abstract class Repository<TEntity, TContext>
    where TEntity : class
    where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    private DbSet<TEntity> _set;

    public TContext ActiveContext { get; set; }

    protected Repository()
    {
        ActiveContext = new TContext();
    }

    public DbSet<TEntity> Set
    {
        get { return _set ?? (_set = ActiveContext.Set<TEntity>()); }
    }

    public TEntity Create()
    {
        return Set.Create();
    }

    public int Add(TEntity item)
    {
        Set.Add(item);
        return ActiveContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public int Remove(TEntity item)
    {
        Set.Remove(item);
        return ActiveContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public int Update()
    {
        return ActiveContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**ArchiveRepository:**

```
public class ArchiveRepository : Repository<PersonIdentificationImage, Contexts.ArchiveBoundedContext>, IArchiveRepository
{
    public ArchiveRepository() { }

    public void AddPersonIdentificationImage(PersonIdentificationImage personIdentificationImage)
    {
        var ctx = ActiveContext;
        ctx.PersonIdentificationImages.Add(personIdentificationImage);
    }
}
```

**ArchiveService:**

```
public class ArchiveService : IArchiveService
{
    private readonly ArchiveRepository _archiveRepository;

    public ArchiveService()
    {
        _archiveRepository = new ArchiveRepository();
    }
}
```

**QTasArchiveBaseContext:**

```
public class QTasArchiveBaseContext<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext 
{
    static QTasArchiveBaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null);
    }

    protected QTasArchiveBaseContext()
        : base(DatabaseSettings.Default.QTasArchiveDatabaseConString)
    { }
}
```

**ArchiveBoundedContext:**

```
public class ArchiveBoundedContext : QTasArchiveBaseContext<ArchiveBoundedContext>
{
    public DbSet<PersonOtherImage> PersonScannedImages { get; set; }

    public DbSet<PersonIdentificationImage> PersonIdentificationImages { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where's the definition for `ArchiveBoundedContext.Infrastructure.Contexts.ArchiveBoundedContext`?

Comment: @David add ArchiveBoundedContext to end of my question.

Comment: And... What is `QTasArchiveBaseContext<T>`?  According to the error `ArchiveBoundedContext` can't be used as a `DbContext`.  Should it be?

Comment: @David I describe ArchiveBoundedContext  in my question. it's before ArchiveBoundedContext. public class QTasArchiveBaseContext<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext { }

Comment: Why your repository inherits from IEnumerable?

Comment: @FabioLuz I fixed it. but my problem still there.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Repository` class, replace the `DbContext` for `class`:

```
  public abstract class Repository<TEntity, TContext>
    where TEntity : class
    where TContext : DbContext, new()

  public abstract class Repository<TEntity, TContext>
        where TEntity : class
        where TContext : class
{
     private DbSet<TEntity> _set;

     public TContext ActiveContext { get; set; }

     public Repository(TContext dbContext)
     {
          ActiveContext = dbContext;
     }

     ....
}
```

Does that work?

Comment: No, If I describe TContext as class and I can't use it functions like SaveChanges().

Comment: Error 1 'TContext' is a 'type parameter' but is used like a 'variable' F:\Last Version Of Projects\Archiver-master\SharedKernel.Infrastructure\Repository.cs 21 40 SharedKernel.Infrastructure

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You have to pass the dbContext in the constructor. The constructor must be public